# Do I pay tax in New Zealand or Australia as a resident of Bolivia but citizen of Australia?

Tags: income-tax, non-resident, australia, new-zealand, bolivia

I reside in Bolivia although I am an Australian citizen (but regarded as a non-resident of Australia for taxation purposes.)

I was invited to teach a series of workshops in New Zealand over a 2-week period.

To whom do I pay tax for this income?

On my Australian tax return, I am only taxed on Australian-sourced income.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know nothing about any Bolivian liability. As you say, you're not Australian tax resident, so there shouldn't be a liability there.

The [NZ government website](https://www.classic.ird.govt.nz/international/comingleaving/coming/payingtax/coming-to-nz-payingtax.html#targetText=New%20Zealand%20has%20a%20pay,to%20us%20on%20your%20behalf.) has a reasonably clear explanation:

> **New Zealand source income**
>
> New Zealand will also tax income obtained by a non-resident if it has a New Zealand source. This is known as source based taxation.
>
> Generally, income will have a New Zealand source if it has a connection with New Zealand. Examples of income with a New Zealand source include:
>
> - income derived from employment performed in New Zealand even if the employer is a non-resident
> - pensions paid by the New Zealand government
> - dividends paid by New Zealand companies.

I believe your situation is covered by the first bullet. I believe it's stated that way because it also applies if the employer **is** tax resident.

There's the possibility of an exemption:

> **Short term visit exemption**
>
> This exemption applies if:
>
> a. your stay in New Zealand is for 92 days or less, counting the days of your arrival and departure as a whole day each
>
> b.  the total number of days that you're present in New Zealand in the tax year (1 April to 31 March) is 92 days or less
>
> c. you're working for an employer that isn't resident in New Zealand, and
>
> d. the income you earn while in New Zealand is taxed in your home country (the country where you're tax resident).

I believe you can't get this  because your employer **is** NZ tax resident, but you might want to check with them.